# How to add character limits, get length of comments, find characters left, condition if you go over 255 characters

Tags: javascript, html

How would add a counter so it reads "you have 0 characters of your 255".

How do I find the function of the characters?

Also how can I define the event that triggers the keystroke, would it be onkeyup/onkeydown?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showComment(){ 
  //get the length of the comments.
  //find the characters left by subtracting 255 - length
  //condition if we go over 255
  //disable the field or just make the value equal to the first 255 characters.
}    
    
</script>    
    
    
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"  placeholder="fullname"><span class="err"></span><br>
<div id ="showcomment" >You have <span id="numleft"></span> characters of your 255 left!</div>        
<textarea id="comments"  maxlength="255"></textarea>   
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"> 
    </form>
</body>    
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a rudimentary version of what you could do:

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="showComment()">

<form action="" method="post">    
<input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname"  placeholder="fullname"><span class="err"></span><br>
<div id ="showcomment" >You have <span id="numleft"></span> characters of your 255 left!</div>        
<textarea id="comments"  maxlength="255"></textarea>   
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Enter"> 
    </form>
</body>
   <script>
const txt=document.getElementById("comments"),
      numleft=document.getElementById("numleft"),
      submit=document.getElementById("submit");
txt.oninput=showComment;

function showComment(){ 
  submit.disabled=((numleft.textContent=255-txt.value.length)==0);

}    
    
</script>    
</html>
```

Please note that I moved the script section to the bottom of the page as this makes sure it is executed after the `body` has been processed.

The function will not need to limit the input string itself, as HTML5 in connection with `maxlength` will already take care of that. As an "extra effect" I disabled the submit button when the limit is reached. This is only for demonstration and doesn't make sense in a real application.

Comment: thank you for your help on this. One questions, on the "txt.oninput=showComment; Is that attribute an alternative to the onekeyup or onekeydown?.. Again thank you..

Comment: `oninput` will also trigger when you change the contents of the input element by mouse-methods like cut and paste. It obviously also includes anything you can do with your keyboard.